# Minifying css classes and ids

Tags: css, node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp

I want to find some way of automatically minifying classes and ids in a .html-file. The file is created through a series of gulp commands. I've tried the command line application Munch, but it ruins the file since it removes doctype and important comments that I have. Does anyone have any tip on how to do this? The best option would of course be something like this:

```
.pipe(minifyClassesAndIds({ignoreclasses: ['.this', '.that']})
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The only working tool I know is a [HTML Muncher](http://htmlmuncher.com/).
But, unfortunately now it doesn't work very well and have much of issues.

**UPD.** Don't sure about which munch you are talking about, is it the same as HTML Muncher?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.